# How to delete unnecessary text when extract from PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, exact-match

I am using Apache PDFBox to extract text from a scientific paper. I can extract the text from the PDF file.

Below is the code for extracting plain text from the PDF. For example, data to extract: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P/P16/P16-2015.pdf.

I just want to get the title and body text, not the references and the author's name on the first page - `Yanhui Gu 1 Zhenglu Yang 2∗ .... - > {xingtian.shi }@sap.com`.

```
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
    PDDocument pdDoc = null;
    COSDocument cosDoc = null;
    int count = 1;
    String directory = "Result";
    File folder = new File("data");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            try {
              String t;
              String text = getText(file);
              t=text.replaceAll("\n|\r|\t", "");
              printFile(directory+"\\data"+count+".txt",t);
              count++;
             } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is hard without any example data ... but I would guess: you can use some regular expression pattern matching if the data to exclude looks similar on all documents.

Comment: ok. thanks. I also think use regular expression pattern. But I just learn some simple pattern. Can you help me

Comment: If you know where it is, then use PDFTextStripperByArea (see the ExtractTextByArea example in the source code)

Comment: A problem is that humans creating such papers are very innovative concerning how to put and formulate such information, and humans reading them are used to that. Fixed regular expressions on the other hand will often fail. Thus, unless you only are interested in articles from sources which enforce a certain style (magazines often do), you will often have to update your expression.